# Multilingual Website practice

Tags: php, html, css, multilingual

I am a beginner and have to do my first webpage in two languages. 
And I don't really know, how to make this work. It should be a simple portfolio page. 
Should I make:

1. 2 pages, one for "en" and one for "fr"
2. make a PHP page and create a database with all the text to be shown for each language? If I make this db should the hosting of the client have some special options to receive php? (I`ve read it somewhere and want to validate it).

Maybe I have asked some awkward question but: Answer me from your practice how you would do this multilingual website.

Comment: You aren't using any framework?

Comment: Like many things it depends. For a simple portfolio page, which are two HTML pages I 'd go the simplest way. Just code down two html pages. If the page is supposed to be extendable (like adding a contact form, etc.), I 'd suggest the PHP variant. With PHP I suggest to split up the content in two categories. First simple phrases, which can be placed in a simple array. Second whole Articles / longer phrases, which I 'd place in a database. A simple MySQL 5.x database and PHP 7 should work.

Comment: @DevNiels no framework.

Comment: you could use javascript and have both texts in the same page but only the one visible , the one corresponding in the users lang choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have more or less identified, you have three broad options:

1. Write 2 separate HTML webpages and edit each one separately with a text-editor
2. Write a single server-side file using PHP (or any other server-side scripting language) and use the server-side engine to create the page and populate it with either English content or French content
3. Write a single client-side page using javascript (and possibly Ajax and JSON etc.) and use the client-side script to to populate the page with either English content or French content

   **N.B.** If you go for Option 2 (the server side approach) **you do not need a database**. Unless your page is extraordinarily complex, an array will likely suffice.